# Dump using BINARY SEARCH in ABAP?

Tags: abap, binary-search

Is it possible to cause program dump using BINARY SEARCH in READ statement in ABAP ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? What have you tried, what is the exact error message?

Comment: It is just question I heard at the meeting if it is possible to cause dump using BINARY SEARCH. Without any other specification or scenarios.

Comment: No, thats not possible. `BINARY SEARCH` is just another way of going through the table (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)). If nothing is found, your field-symbol may stays unassigned but that is not the fault of the binary search itself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes is possible.
One example can be

```
READ TABLE itab ASSIGNING <fs_itab> WITH KEY keyfield1 = key1
                                             keyfield2 = key2
                                             BINARY SEARCH.
```

if there no date in you itab that you find, the field symbol was not assigned and you will get a dump.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed.  Dump is not possible from the binary search clause alone.  However, if the table is not sorted, the search may not find the record.  Which could possibly lead to a dump if you don't check to make sure the record was found first.